# Idiom for "nothing bad will happen" or" nothing bad will not happen"?

Tags: idioms, double-negation, phrase-usage

I just was talking with my Enlish friend and I wanted to use a construction:

> If yes - ok, if not - nothing bad will happen, right?

I am Russian and I am unsure if there is such idiom in English. It means that if not, no bad things will happen.

Also, did I used it correctly? Does "Nothing bad will happen" = "Nothing bad wouldn't happen"? (In my "Russian" mind it is stated this way.)

Comment: Your construction itself is a valid way to express this. A further, slightly more sophisticated example of use might be in answer to, 'Should I ask her out? What if she laughs?' You could reply, 'Why not? If she says yes, ok/great, if she says no, all you have lost is time and if she is mean, you dodged a bullet/don't want to waste time on her anyway.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, there is an understanding that a **double negative** equals a positive.

Your example:

> Nothing bad wouldn't happen...

means *everything that is bad would happen*. Why? *No* thing which is bad would  *not* happen.

The idiom is common in English as well. Often it's expressed *either way, it's ok*, or *either way, it's good.*

"Bad publicity or good publicity, it still exposes people to our mission. Either way, it's good."

> If yes, ok; if not, nothing bad will happen, right? (punctuation edited)

is fine, as you did not use a double negative here. The *not* is separated from *nothing*. For a more common expression, make the last part a positive instead of a non-negative:

> If yes, great; if not, it's still good, right?

Comment: You should get a vote for understanding the question.

Answer (score 0):

What's the worst that could happen?

Comment: This *doesn't look* an answer until one reads the OP's post. Could you please explain the reason for "What' the worst that could happen" instead of "nothing bad will happen"